# Php readfile('/home/myhome/video.mp4')

Tags: php, file, file-upload

hello I've been working on this script for two weeks and I can't figure out how to do it.
I am working in PHP and I want to download videos, the problem in that the "readfile" function doesn't work with files out of /var/www, that is a problem because I have many videos and not enough space in the / partition. Here is my script thanks.

```
$fichero = "/home/myhome/Video/$video";

if (file_exists($fichero)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fichero));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fichero));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($fichero);
        exit;
}else{
    die("The File $fichero does not exist");
}
```

I double checked the address and I increased the maximum size of download, so please if you have any solutions, that would be great.

Comment: It should work on them.  What are the permissions going in to your video directory?  You could also create a link to you `video` directory from within your `www` directory and make sure all files are global readable (`+r`).

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here? How does the `/var/www` relate to `/home/myhome/Video` that's mentioned in the script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use mod rewrite to do this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

Use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
Alias /videos /home/myhome/Video
```

Which will map any file in `/home/myhome/Video/` to `www.site.com/videos/`

Or you can be a bit more specific and have regex based matching:

```
RewriteEngine On
ScriptAliasMatch ^/videos/([^\.])+.mp4 /home/myhome/Video/$1.mp4
```

Which will map any file which matches the rule: `/videos/everythingexepctadot.mp4` and maps it to `/home/myhome/Video/matchedtext.mp4`

Couple this with some RewriteCond's and you have youself a simple way of serving up data from non web root directories.

Comment: it almost worked but i am having problems with the permissions. I changed them to 777 but still i get error 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Please check directory read/write permissions first. Just Try below code for dynamically setting permission.

```
chmod("/home/myhome/Video/", 0644);

$fichero = "/home/myhome/Video/$video";

if (file_exists($fichero)) {
 //Your Code   
}else{
//Your Code   
}
```

Cheers,
**JENSon.**